# payment method for ios version

Tags: ios, app-store, payment, applepay, payment-method

i am creating an iOS app , its for my shop so i sell products ,
so when the client will place an order i use methods : pay with bank card ( i got the code from my bank ).

**my question is** : should i add apple pay to can be accepted on apple store ?
or they can accept it without integrating apple pay ?

> and for more specifications : i didn't use any solution like **stripe or PayPal** ..

Thank you
[image]

Comment: You don't have to accept Apple Pay, but it does offer a simple payment experience for users; they don't have to enter credit card or address details. Note that Apple Pay is not in app purchase (which is required if you are selling digital goods, which you are not). Also, by convention the currency symbol comes before the amount (so "Total: $79.20")

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you for your advice will use the symbol like you mention . so please , if i deploy my app on app stroe without apple pay it will not be rejected ?

Comment: Well, it won't be rejected for not using Apple Pay. Apple Pay is optional.